# How to get video files from android external storage in a specific folder location

Tags: android, android-external-storage

i need to access external video file for my project when i run this code i get error message which shows "Unfortunatly you app stopped". pls let me know my mistake. and giude me how to do that and let me know how to handle the external file storages.

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity 
    {
      private File file;
      private List<String> myList;

     EditText et;
     Button bt;


  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      bt =  (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
      et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
      String txt = et.getText().toString();

      myList = new ArrayList<String>();   



     String root_sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
     file = new File( root_sd + "/videos/"+txt ) ;       
     File list[] = file.listFiles();

    for( int i=0; i< list.length; i++)
       {
        myList.add( list[i].getName() );
        }

    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myList ));

 }

   protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) 
     {
       super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

      File temp_file = new File( file, myList.get( position ) );  

     if( !temp_file.isFile())        
      {
       file = new File( file, myList.get( position ));
        File list[] = file.listFiles();

         myList.clear();

       for( int i=0; i< list.length; i++)
         {
           myList.add( list[i].getName() );
           }
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),file.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();               
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myList ));

       }

     }


   @Override
     public void onBackPressed() {
        String parent = file.getParent().toString();
        file = new File( parent ) ;         
        File list[] = file.listFiles();

        myList.clear();

        for( int i=0; i< list.length; i++)
        {
            myList.add( list[i].getName() );
        }
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), parent,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myList ));


    }
   }
```

Comment: What is typed in txt? A foldername? You should first check if that folder exists before requiesting a list. And if it does not contain files list[] will be null. So check that otherwise list.length will bring you a NullPointerException. You did not post the logcat. Maybe you did not even look in the logcat. Do. As it will tell you exactly what went wrong. Post a relevant part of the logcat then.

Comment: add permission to manifest - <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

Comment: Try to get the path of sdcard by using: `String root_sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/";`

Comment: can i give direct folder name instead of using Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() method.

Answer (score 0):

please follow this links:

http://android-coding.blogspot.in/2011/03/using-videoview-to-play-mp4-from-sdcard.html

and make sure to give these two lines

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

into the manifest after

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
```

like this

hope it will work..

Answer (score 0):

Have you include permissions in your manifest file..?
Try this

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```